# bibliographystyle "unsrt" not working

Tags: bibliographies

I am using `unsrt` for bibliographystyle but getting an incorrect sequence in the References section in the pdf. Here's the content of the .tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\title{\textbf{\large{Title Goes Here}}}
\author{
Author Name
}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction} 
I am using unsrt.
I want to cite these two: ~\cite{JMechPhysSol_analytical} and ~\cite{OrigPaper}.
But they appear in the reverse order.
\begin{thebibliography}{00}
  \bibitem{OrigPaper}
  J. Cheng, E. H. Jordan, B. Barber, M. Gell, 
  ``Thermal/Residual Stress in an Electron Beam Physical Vapor Deposited Thermal Barrier          
  \textit{Acta Mater.}, \textbf{46}, 5839-5850 (1998).
  \bibitem{JMechPhysSol_analytical}
  D. S. Balint, J.W. Hutchinson,
  ``An Analytical model of rumpling in thermal barrier coatings.''
  \textit{J. Mech. Phys. Solids}, \textbf{53}, 949-973 (2005).

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Here's the ouput:

[image]

Comment: If you typeset the bibliography manually, the order will always be the one in which you declare the entries. `\bibliographystyle` won't have any effect unless you use BibTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to let BibTeX perform the organization (and sorting, if needed) of your bibliography. If you enter the `\bibitem`s manually, there's no way it will be sorted/arranged according to your style (`unsrt`). So, follow the sequence:

1. Write your bibliography in a separate `.bib` file using the appropriate [BibTeX entry format](http://www.bibtex.org/Format/).
2. Compile `filename.tex` once (in order to obtain a correct/current `.aux`).
3. Run `bibtex filename` (in order to obtain a correct/current `.bbl`).
4. Compile `filename.tex` again (in order to include the correct/current `.bbl`).

Here's an example with the `.bib` embedded in the `.tex` using [`filecontents`](http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{OrigPaper,
  author = {J Cheng and EH Jordan and B Barber and M Gell},
  title = {Thermal/Residual Stress in an Electron Beam Physical Vapor Deposited Thermal Barrier},
  journal = {Acta Mater.},
  volume = {46},
  pages = {5839-5850},
  year = {1998}
}
@article{JMechPhysSol_analytical,
  author = {DS Balint and JW Hutchinson},
  title = {An Analytical model of rumpling in thermal barrier coatings.},
  journal = {J.\ Mech.\ Phys.\ Solids},
  volume = {53},
  pages = {949-973},
  year = {2005}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\title{\textbf{\large{Title Goes Here}}}
\author{Author Name}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction} 
I am using \verb|unsrt|.
I want to cite these two:~\cite{JMechPhysSol_analytical} and~\cite{OrigPaper}.

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Note how there was no specification of formatting for the journal or number in the `.bib` - all of that was done by BibTeX.